# Get a list of property elements using GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I'm using GeoServer with openlayers and I want to build a filter check-box dynamically, depending on the elements of this column:

[image: Column]

How can I query GeoServer so that I get a list of the different elements in this column?
Or at least all the information of all the columns in XML so that I can parse it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the WFS support is enabled on your GeoServer you can check the schema of the layer with DescribeFeatureType http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=topp:states

All the information of all the columns in XML so that you can parse it? Read all the data with WFS GetFeature http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states

A list of the different elements in one column? WFS is missing equivalent to "select distinct" in SQL but all the values from one column can be fetched by restricting the total GetFeature with &PROPERTYNAME http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&PROPERTYNAME=STATE_NAME

GeoJSON may please you more so select your outputformat http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&PROPERTYNAME=STATE_NAME&outputformat=application/json

You seem to get the BBOX of features as extra from this certain server.

WFS layers can hold millions of features. Do not fire plain GetFeature blindly without any filters.

Comment: Thank you very much. This will do the trick. I'll add the distinct to a list programatically or something. I was close, but didn't quite got it.